# Safe code for SQL Injection using mysql_*

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-injection

I just want to know if there's a way of making your code using `mysql_*` safe for SQL Injection.

I have this code inside my log.php:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

include("conn.php");

if($username && $password)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_users WHERE username='$username'");
    if($query!=0)
    {
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $db_username = $rows['username'];
            $db_password = $rows['password'];
        }

        if($username == $db_username && $password == $db_password)
        {
            header("location: stud.php");
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['stud_num'] = $db_stud_num;
            break;
        }       
    }
}
```

How can I test this for SQL Injection?

I found a out some ideas that `http://127.0.0.1/test/index.php?username=%27%20or%201=1%20/*&password=1` can use to test my website for SQL injection vulnerabilities. But doesn't worked.

I also try typing inside the input fields `1 OR 1 = 1; --` but still doesn't work.

I know that it maybe because of the condition I set inside my code but how can I know other hackers strategy for SQL Injection?

maybe just give me some easy-to-use tools for testing local websites.

Thanks for enlightening me :D

Comment: You aren't really thinking this through. Consider what happens when the given input goes into your SQL string. All of it remains in the quotes. So you have to ask yourself how you'd get out of the quotes.

Comment: Hmmmmmm,for example?

Comment: "maybe just give me some easy-to-use tools for testing local websites". If it was easy to test for injection attacks they wouldn't be nearly so common. You can't just run a few tools against your site to make sure it's secure. Security has to come from the ground up, with careful planning.

Comment: @ArchieZineg: do what I said and try putting your examples into the SQL string (on paper) and consider what would happen if you execute the SQL. Then try to figure out ways to get out of the quotes, out of the query, etc. It's not hard. I'm not going to spoonfeed you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and @siride thanks for concern, I do what you say. :D

Comment: Also, if this is new code please stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Chris, yah I'm using PDO now. I'm just curious and can't totally figured it out. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using mysql_* code. If you have beginning of the project rewrite all code to mysqli or PDO. (PDO is better.)

If you want to use mysql_* use mysql_real_escape_string in all input field.

You can read more [Here](http://www.greensql.com/article/protect-yourself-sqli-attacks-create-backdoor-web-server-using-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);


 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_users WHERE username='$username'");
```